# ruby - get a file from directory without listing all contents

Tags: ruby

I'm using the split linux command to split huge xml files into node-sized ones. The problem is now I have directory with hundreds of thousands of files.

I want a way to get a file from the directory (to pass to another process for import into our database) without needing to list everything in it. Is this how `Dir.foreach` already works? Any other ideas?

Comment: Dir.foreach is the right solution if you're going to process all the files.  You might want to consider using a unique subdirectory for all node-files of a parent xml file (when you use linux split).

Comment: Yeah, that's a good idea, but it only partially solves the problem because one file is much bigger than the others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Dir.glob` to find the files you need. More details [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Dir.html#M002322), but basically, you pass it a pattern like `Dir.glob 'dir/*.rb'` and get back filenames matching that pattern. I assume it's done in a reasonably good way, but it will depend on your platform and implementation.

As to `Dir.foreach`, this should be efficient too - the concern would be if it has to process the entire directory for every pass around the loop. But that would be awful implementation, and is not the case.